# CSS3 Multiple Background-Image Not working

Tags: css, background-image

I have two background images that i would like to place on the left and right side of my wrapper div. I am using CSS3 background-image property to do this but it is not working. Can anyone make sense as to why this is not working in any browsers. I would also like to know once i get this working on modern browsers will it work on older browser like IE 7?

Here is a visual of what i'm trying to accomplish i've have the navigation (green banner) already in place so i need to put the tricky red banner on and circle background.

I thought slicing the edges of the red banner along with the circle background and applying the code below would work but it does not being that I need the sides to stay flush to the sides.

[image]

```
body{ 
    background-color:#e5e5e5; 
    background-image: url("../img/background_left.png"),url("../img/background_right.png");
    background-position: right top, left top; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add height to your `<body>` and it will work - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XjJR6/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body{ 
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-color:      #e5e5e5; 
    background-image:      url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200), url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300);
    background-position:   right top, left top; 
    background-repeat:     no-repeat, no-repeat;
} ​
```

But it won't work in older IE-s - [multiple backgrounds support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)

Comment: Zoltan first of all thank you for helping me with this problem. Your code does place the background images to the left and right of the body but it does not stay flush to the sides.